# Replacing X & O in Tic Tac Toe With Images

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EOrRXo
This is my code so far. It just uses JS to generate a bunch of styled divs. I don't know how to input a picture instead of a string to fill in my divs. They all have values that I add up to generate each players' score to use bitwise "&" calculation to determine when someone has won. There's a play again button that works but it's broken for you because the image is local. Also it's extreme so it's spinning and I'm sorry if that annoys you.

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EXTREME TIC TAC TOE</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "startGame();">
        <h2 id="game-message"> Tic Tac Toe </h2>
        <div id="game-board">
        </div>
        <div  id="restartButton" >
        <img src="img/lets-play.gif" id="button" onclick="restartGame();">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

CSS
/* CSS */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; user-select: none; text-transform: uppercase;}
body {background-image: url('../img/name.type'); }
h2#game-message
{
    font-size: 60px; 
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#game-board
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width:870px;
}
div[id^="row-"] {clear: both;}
div [id^="row-"] div
{
    //border: 30px solid plum;
    height: 270px;
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 175px;

    border-width: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url('../img/border.jpg') 25% repeat;
}
div#row-1 div {border-top: none;}
div#row-3 div {border-bottom: none;}
div[id^="row-"] div:first-child {border-left: none}
div[id^="row-"] div:last-child {border-right: none}

#button
{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url('../img/borderr.png') 25% round;

}
#restartButton
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 880px;
    top: 1075px;
}
@keyframes rotation 
{
    from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
            transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {left: 0;}
    100% { left: 1500px;}
}
#game-board
{
    position: relative;
}

JS

//JAVASCRIPT
var markers = ["X", "O"];
//var players = [];
var players = ["Max", "Dennis"]; 
var totals = [];
var winCodes = [7,56,73,84,146,273,292,448];
var whoseTurn = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var speed = [2, 2];


// Play again button
function restartGame()
{

    startGame();
}
function startGame() // Choose your names, and display them in the header message.
{
    // makes board spin initially
    document.getElementById("game-board").style.animation = "rotation 4s infinite linear";
    //players[0] = prompt("Player 1 NAME:");
    //players[1] = prompt("Player 2 NAME:");
    var counter = 1;
    var innerDivs = "";
    for (i = 1; i <=3; i++)
    {
        innerDivs += '<div id="row-' + i + '">';

        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            innerDivs += '<div onclick="playGame(this,' + counter + ');"></div>';
            counter *= 2;
        }
        innerDivs += '</div>';
    }

    document.getElementById("game-board").innerHTML = innerDivs;
    totals = [0, 0];
    gameOver = false;
    document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "IT'S YOUR TURN " + players[whoseTurn];
}

function playGame(clickedDiv, divValue)
{
    if (!gameOver)
    {   
    // changes speed depending on how many turns each player has done
    speed[whoseTurn]++;
    document.getElementById("game-board").style.animation = "rotation "+  8 / speed[whoseTurn] + "s infinite linear";

        // Adds X or O depending on whoseTurn
        clickedDiv.innerText = markers[whoseTurn]; 

        // adds up total each time a player "moves" to track a win condition
        totals[whoseTurn] += divValue;

        // calls isWin() function to see if someone won
        if (isWin())
        {
            document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "WOW VERY COOL " + players[whoseTurn] + " YOU WON";
            document.getElementById("game-board").style.animation = "slide 2s forwards, rotation "+  8 / speed[whoseTurn] + "s infinite linear";
        }
        else if (gameOver)
        {
            document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "YOU BOTH FAILED";
        }
        else
        {
        // Switches turn each click
        if (whoseTurn) whoseTurn = 0; else whoseTurn = 1; 

        // disables onclick tag after clicked so it cannot be used >1 times.
        clickedDiv.attributes["0"].nodeValue = ""; 

        // Displays text for which turn it is
        document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "IT'S YOUR TURN " + players[whoseTurn];
        }
    }
}

// win code logic
function isWin()
{
    for (i = 0; i < winCodes.length; i++)
    {
        if ((totals[whoseTurn] & winCodes[i]) == winCodes[i]) {gameOver = true;  return true;}
    }
    if (totals[0] + totals[1] == 511) {gameOver = true;}

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You put a marker in the div now, put an image instead. You’re already putting html in there dynamically so that isn’t a big leap

Answer (score 0):

You can start by replacing the `markers` array with (or creating a new array, such as `markerImages`) [image elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Then replace `clickedDiv.innerText` with `clickedDiv.innerHTML`.

Comment: Okay so I changed my markers array to var markers = ["<img src='placekitten.com/100/100'", "O"]; and innerText to innerHTML clickedDiv.innerHTML = markers[whoseTurn]; however nothing happens when it's player one's turn and I click and I am still not understanding why. If I put "" instead of '' around the url the whole tic tac toe disappears.

Comment: @MaxDecker You're not properly closing the img tag, nor are you correctly linking to your image. You should use `http://placekitten.com/100/100`. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaqNdP